Source for 613 Gates to Emunah
I heard in a shiur that the Zohar says each one of the 613 mitzvos is a gate to Emunah. I would like to find the Zohar to see it myself.

Perhaps the Zohar Yitro 82b is the source:
The Zohar in Yitro 82b says:

"וידבר אלהים את כל הדברים האלה לאמר, רבי יהודה פתח (תהלים קו) מי ימלל גבורות יי' ישמיע כל תהלתו, בכמה ארחין אורייתא אסהידת בבר נש דלא יחוב קמי מאריה, בכמה ארחין יהיב ליה עיטא דלא יסטי מארחוי לימינא ולשמאלא, בכמה ארחין יהיב ליה עיטא היך יתוב קמי מאריה וימחול ליה דתנן שית מאה ותלת עשר זיני עיטא יהיב אורייתא לבר נש למהוי שלים במאריה בגין דמאריה בעא לאוטבא ליה בעלמא דין ובעלמא דאתי, ויתיר בעלמא דאתי דהא תנינן כל מה דקודשא בריך הוא אשלים ליה לבר נש מאינון טבאן דזכי בהו לעלמא דאתי אשתלים בהו".

"And God spoke all these words, saying: Rabbi Yehudah began, (Tehillim 106) 'Who can express the mighty acts of the Lord? Who can make all His praise heard?' In how many ways did the Torah testify about a person, so that he would not sin before his Master? In how many ways did it give him advice so that he would not turn from his ways, neither to the right nor to the left? In how many ways did it give him advice on how to return to his Master and be forgiven? We have learned that the Torah gave six hundred and thirteen types of advice to a person to be complete with his Master, because the Master desires to do good for him in this world and in the world to come, and more so in the world to come, for we have learned that all that Hashem completed for a person was from those good things that he merits in the world to come, he was perfected by them."
One can understand the words שית מאה ותלת עשר זיני עיטא יהיב אורייתא לבר נש למהוי שלים במאריה, to mean, "there are 613 ways of advice (mitzvot) that were given to a person to be complete with his master- to be complete meaning to be have full emunah in Hashem. Through this a person can attain olam hazeh and olam haba through his emunah which can be achieved by every mitzvah (of the 613 a person does):
I have added here the Likutei Halachot, Rebbe Nathan Sternhartz of Nemirov who explains this Zohar as well (although I know you do not want a commentary necessarily):

וְזֶה בְּחִינַת שָׁבוּעוֹת בְּחִינַת מַתַּן תּוֹרָה, כִּי עִקַּר קַבָּלַת הַתּוֹרָה וְהַמִּצְוֹת הוּא הָאֱמוּנָה שֶׁהוּא" יְסוֹד כָּל הַתּוֹרָה וְהַמִּצְוֹת כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב (תְּהִלִּים קיט), כָּל מִצְוֹתֶיךָ אֱמוּנָה, וּכְמוֹ שֶׁדָּרְשׁוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה (מַכּוֹת כד), בָּא חֲבַקּוּק וְהֶעֱמִידָן עַל אַחַת וְצַדִּיק בֶּאֱמוּנָתוֹ יִחְיֶה, וְעַל-כֵּן תְּחִלַּת דְּבַר ה' שֶׁדִּבֵּר עִם יִשְֹרָאֵל הוּא אָנֹכִי ה' אֱלֹקֶיךָ וְכוּ' שֶׁהִיא עִקַּר הָאֱמוּנָה לְהַאֲמִין בַּה' יִתְבָּרַךְ וּלְבַטֵּל אֱמוּנוֹת כּוֹזְבִיּוֹת בְּחִינַת לֹא יִהְיֶה לְךָ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים לֹא תַעֲשֶֹה לְךָ פֶסֶל וְכוּ', כִּי זֶהוּ עִקַּר הַהַתְחָלָה וְהַתַּכְלִית וְהַיְסוֹד וְהָעִקָּר שֶׁל כָּל הַתּוֹרָה כֻּלָּה, כִּי הָעִקָּר הוּא הָאֱמוּנָה כַּנַּ"ל, לְהַעֲלוֹת הָאֱמוּנָה צְרִיכִין לַחְתֹּר הַמַּיִם שֶׁמֵּהֶם גְּדֵלָה הָאֱמוּנָה שֶׁהֵם בְּחִינַת עֵצוֹת וְכוּ' כַּנַּ"ל, וְזֶה בְּחִינַת תרי"ג עִטִּין דְּאוֹרַיְתָא שֶׁהוּא כְּלָלִיּוּת הַתּוֹרָה שֶׁכְּלוּלִין בַּעֲשֶֹרֶת הַדִּבְּרוֹת שֶׁמְּקַבְּלִין בְּשָׁבוּעוֹת, כִּי כְּלָלִיּות הַתּוֹרָה נִקְרֵאת עֵצָה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁכָּתוּב, לִי עֵצָה וְתוּשִׁיָּה אֲנִי בִינָה וְכוּ', בְּחִינַת תרי"ג עִטִּין דְּאוֹרַיְתָא, כִּי עִקָּר כָּל מִצְווֹת הַתּוֹרָה הֵם בְּחִינַת עֵצוֹת קְדוֹשׁוֹת שֶׁהֵם בְּחִינַת מַיִם עֲמוּקִים עֵצָה וְכוּ', שֶׁעַל יָדָם גְּדֵלָה הָאֱמוּנָה, כִּי עִקַּר תַּכְלִית הַתּוֹרָה הוּא הָאֱמוּנָה לְגַלּוֹת אֱמוּנָה הַקְּדוֹשָׁה בָּעוֹלָם, לְמַעַן דַּעַת כָּל עַמֵּי הָאָרֶץ כִּי ה' הוּא הָאֱלֹקִים וְכוּ' וְכַנַּ"ל. וְעַל-כֵּן נָתַן לָנוּ תרי"ג עִטִּין דְּאוֹרַיְתָא שֶׁהֵם תרי"ג מִצְווֹת שֶׁנִּקְרָאִים עֵצוֹת, כִּי עַל-יְדֵי הָעֵצוֹת גְּדֵלָה הָאֱמוּנָה שֶׁהוּא עִקָּר הַכֹּל כַּנַּ"ל."

"This is the concept of Shavuot, which is the aspect of receiving the Torah, because the essence of accepting the Torah and the commandments is faith, which is the foundation of all the Torah and the commandments. As it is written (Psalms 119:86), "All Your commandments are faith," and as our Rabbis, of blessed memory, expounded (Makkot 24a), "Chavkuk came and established them upon one principle: 'The righteous shall live by his faith.'" Therefore, the first thing that God spoke to Israel was "I am the Lord your God," which is the essence of faith, to believe in Hashem and to nullify false beliefs, as in "You shall have no other G-d's before Me, you shall not make for yourself a graven image," etc. For this is the primary beginning, purpose, foundation, and essence of the entire Torah, for the main thing is faith, as mentioned above.
To elevate faith, one needs to seek the waters from which faith grows, which are in the aspect of advice, as mentioned above. This is the concept of the 613 pieces of advice of the Torah, which is the totality of the Torah included in the Ten Commandments that we receive on Shavuot. The totality of the Torah is called advice, as it is written, "Mine is counsel and sound wisdom; I am understanding," etc. This is the aspect of the 613 pieces of advice of the Torah. For the essence of all the commandments of the Torah are holy pieces of advice, which are in the aspect of deep waters of counsel, etc., through which faith grows. For the main purpose of the Torah is faith, to reveal holy faith in the world, so that all the people of the earth may know that the Lord is God, etc., as mentioned above. Therefore, He gave us the 613 pieces of advice of the Torah, which are the 613 commandments that are called pieces of advice. For through the advice, faith grows, which is the essence of everything, as mentioned above."
Although I acknowledge that the words "advice" is used, I still think that it's closely related to the word "gate" since advice are also gates that lead to different pathways in any situation. The main idea is that through the Torah being 613 suggestions, and pieces of advice all lead to emunah which is the essence of man's relationship with Hashem and the Torah.

I want an answer that says gates to Emunah, as in my question.

The introduction to the Zohar covers this. It discusses how the first commandment of the Torah is בראשית ברא אלהים, i.e. the commandment of יראת י'י, and the Zohar then states

ודא איהי תרעא לאעלא גו מהימנותא
and this is the gate that leads to Emunah

The Sulam explains

וכפי שיעור היראה כן שיעור השראת האמונה
One's fear of Hashem is the measure of one's Emunah

He then arrives at the conclusion that all of the Mitzvot are gates to Emunah in that every Mitzva is included in this first Mitzva, which he defines as reshit. Fear is the beginning of every Mitzva, and without fear it will not produce Emunah:

היראה היא ראשית
ושער לכל מצוה להיותה השער לאמונה
Fear is called reshit, and is the gate to every Mitzva, being the gate to Emunah.

See here also.
The subtle point being made here, I believe (based on what my Rav taught me) is that Hashem is totally beyond us, so it seems impossible that we should be able to have any connection to Him. Hence, He gave us His Mitzvot to connect to Him. Every level of connection we have with Him from performing these Mitzvot is predominantly a connection of Emunah because, as we said, He is totally beyond us, so we cannot grasp Him with our Chochma or Da'at (directly).

I'm looking for something more explicit in the Zohar itself, not necessarily a commentary. Especially not the sulam.

@N.T. did the person giving the shiur give the impression that it definitely wouldn't be (this pashut diyuk made by) the Sulam? AFAIK this Zohar is the source

He quoted the Zohar.  And from what I know about Ashlag, I don't trust his interpretation based on just his say-so.

@N.T. distrust is a bullet-proof vest. Instead of bringing "trust" into it at all, it's not his "say-so", it's an argument. What do you think of the argument?

To me it sounds more like Ashlag means Yirah is the Sha'ar to Emunah, and Emunah is the Sha'ar to every mitzvah. That's the reverse of what I'm looking for.

@N.T. Excellent!

So it's not an answer.
